# Angularjs. Send variable inside html template in tag <script>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I've this widget code inside directive html template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  _hcwp = window._hcwp || [];
  _hcwp.push({widget:"Stream", widget_id:10862, xid:{{_id}});
  (function() {
  if("HC_LOAD_INIT" in window)return;
  HC_LOAD_INIT = true;
  var lang = (navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage || navigator.userLanguage || "en").substr(0, 2).toLowerCase();
  var hcc = document.createElement("script"); hcc.type = "text/javascript"; hcc.async = true;
  hcc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https" : "http")+"://w.hypercomments.com/widget/hc/10862/"+lang+"/widget.js";
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(hcc, s.nextSibling);
  })();
```

Inside  this template have a variable  {{_id}}.

But when angular render this template, variable is not sent inside template.

At some point have to send a variable inside temple for render?

My directives:

```
app.directive('hyperComments', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: './templates/hc.html',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      xid: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log('hello!');
    $timeout(function() {
        _hcwp = window._hcwp || [];
        _hcwp[0]= { widget:"Stream", widget_id: 28172, xid: 31241123};
        // HC.widget("Stream", _hcwp);

        (function() {
          // if("HC_LOAD_INIT" in window)return;
          // var HC_LOAD_INIT = true;
          console.log('in');
          var lang = (navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage || navigator.userLanguage ||  "en").substr(0, 2).toLowerCase();
          var hcc = document.createElement("script"); hcc.type = "text/javascript"; hcc.async = true;
          hcc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https" : "http")+"://w.hypercomments.com/widget/hc/9345/"+lang+"/widget.js";
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
          console.log(s);
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(hcc, s.nextSibling);
          })();
    }, 10000);

}
};
```

});

Template:

< div>
    < div id="hypercomments_widget">
    comments powered by HyperComments
< /div>

Comment: can you provide the full code of your template and directive?

Comment: @AvraamMavridis I provede the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unmatched bracket in the string

```
_hcwp.push({widget:"Stream", widget_id:10862, xid:{{_id}});
```

Regardless of that, it is not syntactically correct and will throw an error, Angular doesn't parse the contents of `<script>`.

Moreover, Angular doesn't handle `<script>` tag in templates (security concerns or oversimplification of jqlite implementation), so

```
app.directive('sample', function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    controller: function ($scope, $window) {
      $scope.bar = 'test';
      $window.foo = $scope.bar
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      var scriptInane = element.find("script")[0];
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.innerHTML = scriptInane.innerHTML;
      scriptInane.parentNode.replaceChild(script, scriptInane); 
    },
    template: '<h1>test</h1><script>console.log(foo); alert(foo);<\/script>'
  };
});
```

Add `angular.forEach` to support multiple scripts. You can do the same thing in less verbose manner if you have jQuery loaded.

Or you can just prepend that `<script>` with another one (since there's a mess with DOM already) where you specify the global variable, so you could skip the `$window.foo =` part.

Anyway, it seem to be an another 'don't try this at home' practice, there may be better ways to embed this widget.